# aws appsync graphql "Expected JSON object for '$[filter]' but got a 'STRING' instead."

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm trying to filter results based on the id of a child on graphql and receiving the following error:

> "Expected JSON object for '$[filter]' but got a 'STRING' instead."

Most of the code was generated by aws amplify.

**Schema**

```
type Company {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    disabled: Int
}

type Customer {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    company: Company!
    disabled: Int
}

input ModelCustomerFilterInput {
    id: ModelIDFilterInput
    name: ModelStringFilterInput
    disabled: ModelIntFilterInput
    company: ModelCompanyFilterInput #added by me
    and: [ModelCustomerFilterInput]
    or: [ModelCustomerFilterInput]
    not: ModelCustomerFilterInput
}

input ModelCompanyFilterInput {
    id: ModelIDFilterInput
    name: ModelStringFilterInput
    disabled: ModelIntFilterInput
    and: [ModelCompanyFilterInput]
    or: [ModelCompanyFilterInput]
    not: ModelCompanyFilterInput
}
```

**Query**

```
query ListCustomers($filter: ModelCustomerFilterInput, $limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
  listCustomers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    __typename
    items {
      __typename
      id
      name
      company {
        __typename
        id
        name
        disabled
      }
      disabled
    }
    nextToken
  }
}

{"filter": {"company": {"id": {"eq": "example"}}}}
```

Comment: Where is the request being made? If it's on a frontend somewhere is the `content-type` set to `application/json`?

Comment: Directly on the aws appsync console. But it gives the same error on angular 8.

Comment: Did you see the response on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=922391 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved my problem.

What I did was change the schema itself in a way that company contains customers.
In fact the problem was poor design of the schema.

I would really like to see a lookup function in graphql, but probably it wasnt designed for it.